# VF vs. VFR Suffix: Whats the Difference?

Tags: terminology, usb-hub, naming-conventions

On Digikey, I have found 2 parts that have the same datasheet and same product attributes, but one is $2 cheaper and has VFR at the end of its name instead of VF.

Here are the products and datasheets:

- [TUSB2036VF](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/TUSB2036VF/382315)
- [TUSB2036](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/TUSB2036VFR/1910069)
- [Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tusb2036.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1640285439755)

In the datasheet, it labels its pinout as the VF package, so I naturally assumed that there would be a VFR package too, but no such luck.

So what's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R refers to packaging on a reel as opposed to individual units.

Answer (score 2):

On page 22, you can see that -VF comes in a tray of 250 parts while -VFR comes on a reel of 1000, from which you can order cut sections or entire reels if you're doing that.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the datasheet with order codes for parts, the R comes in larger 1000 chip reel and the package without the R only has 250 chips.

The chips are identical.